# Find by category_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my search form I have a collection_select feature for picking a category.

```
<% form_tag search_places_path do -%>
   <%= collection_select(:place, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
```

When I try this in the controller:

```
 @places = Place.find(:all, 
                  :conditions => ["category_id = ?", params[:category_id]])
```

I am seeing `category_id = null` in the search log.

When I try-

```
@places = Place.find(:all, 
                  :conditions => ["category_id = ?", params[:place]])
```

I get `(((category_id = '--- \n- category_id\n- \"1\"\n')` in the search log.

What is the proper conditional statement here?

Answer (score 2):

Since `category_id` is coming in "nested" in the `place` object, you need to retrieve it using `params[:place][:category_id]`:

```
@places = Place.all(:conditions => ["category_id = ?", params[:place][:category_id] ])
```